# Kotlin add dynamic constraintLayout at the bottom of another

Tags: android, kotlin

The new ConstraintLayout is inside constraintLayoutPrincipal and I want it to be below constraintLayoutApplianceLoads but what I am getting is that the new constraintLayout is located on top of constraintLayoutPrincipal and not inside constraintLayoutPrincipal below constraintLayoutApplianceLoads. Is it because of something I'm doing wrong?

```
class DwellingsHouseFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentDwellingsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentDwellingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.buttonAddNewLoad.setOnClickListener{
            val newConstraintLayout = createConstraintLayout(requireContext())

            val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
            constraintSet.clone(binding.constraintLayoutPrincipal)

            constraintSet.connect(newConstraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.constraintLayoutApplianceLoads, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
            constraintSet.applyTo(binding.constraintLayoutPrincipal)

            binding.constraintLayoutPrincipal.addView(newConstraintLayout)
        }
    }

    private fun createConstraintLayout(context: Context): ConstraintLayout {
        val constraintLayout = ConstraintLayout(context)
        constraintLayout.id = View.generateViewId()

        val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        constraintLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams

        // TextView 1
        val textView1 = TextView(context)
        textView1.id = View.generateViewId()
        textView1.text = "Appliance "

        // TextView 2
        val textView2 = TextView(context)
        textView2.id = View.generateViewId()
        textView2.text = "by"

        // TextView 3
        val textView3 = TextView(context)
        textView3.id = View.generateViewId()
        textView3.text = "Select the appliance type"

        // Spinner
        val spinner = Spinner(context)
        spinner.id = View.generateViewId()

        val button = Button(context)
        button.id = View.generateViewId()
        button.text = "New Button"

        constraintLayout.addView(textView1)
        constraintLayout.addView(textView2)
        constraintLayout.addView(textView3)
        constraintLayout.addView(spinner)

        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
        constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)

        constraintSet.connect(textView1.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        constraintSet.connect(textView2.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, textView1.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        constraintSet.connect(textView3.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, textView2.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        constraintSet.connect(spinner.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, textView3.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        constraintSet.connect(button.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, spinner.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

        constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)

        return constraintLayout
    }

}
```